# Loopback 4: How to Group By?

Tags: loopback, loopback4

Is there a way in loopback 4 to group the results by a specific field?

I have been unable to find this in the documentation. Is custom SQL therefore the only way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support for this requirement